# Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading angular2/http

Tags: angular, angular2-http, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli for my Angular2 application. Whenever I try to load angular2/http in my Components/Services no error shows in the cli terminal but  in my browser's console it shows this -

> GET http://localhost:4200/angular2/http 404 (Not Found)
>
> Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not
>   Found) loading http://localhost:4200/angular2/http
>         at XMLHttpRequest.desc.set.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
>         at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
>         at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)    Error
>   loading http://localhost:4200/angular2/http as "angular2/http" from
>   http://localhost:4200/app/js-tree.component.js ; Zone:  ; Task:
>   Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:4200/angular2/http
>         at XMLHttpRequest.desc.set.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
>         at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
>         at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)    Error
>   loading http://localhost:4200/angular2/http as "angular2/http" from
>   http://localhost:4200/app/js-tree.component.js

My angular-cli version is 0.0.39

node : 4.2.2

Here goes my system-config.ts

```
const map: any = {
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
};


const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/tree',
  'app/tree/item',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

And my package.json

```
{
  "name": "pankha",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "format": "clang-format -i -style=file --glob=src/**/*.ts",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "0.0.*",
    "clang-format": "^1.0.35",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.14",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^0.5.5",
    "tslint": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

and my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pankha</title>
  <base href="/">
  {{content-for 'head'}}
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Service worker support is disabled by default.
       Install the worker script and uncomment to enable.
       Only enable service workers in production.
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/worker.js').catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error installing service worker: ', err);
      });
    }
  </script>
  -->
</head>
<body>
  <pankha-app>Loading...</pankha-app>

  <script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script> -->




  <script>
    System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
      System.import('main');
    }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. I was not using beta version of angular2
So I had to open my package.json and add this line under the dependencies

```
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
```

Then I opened my terminal and typed

```
npm install
```

It updated my system-config.ts with

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/tree',
  'app/tree/item',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

where it was

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/tree',
  'app/tree/item',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

Comment: you just saved me hours ;)

Answer (score 9):

I think that you forgot to include the `http.dev.js` file in your main HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Note that this only applies to beta versions (not rc ones) but since you use the `angular2/http` module, I guess that you use a beta version.

Comment: I did but it didnt work :( . Do I need to add more code stuffs ?

Comment: In fact, when SystemJS tries to load modules like that it's because it can't find it within the preregistered ones (ones from the angular2.dev.js, http.dev.js, ...).

Comment: Could you provide the content of your HTML main file (script elements and SystemJS configuration)? Which version of Angular2 do you use? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my post , thanks anyway for your concerns :)

Comment: After creating with ng create Project_name , I went to the folder and typed npm install angular2 . So I do see 'http.dev.js' there is in  'node_modules/angular2/bundles/'